# Returning proper state of radio button in PyQt when it's set in the initialization of the GUI

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

- I have a `default_layout` function that sets certain items in the GUI to certain states.
- One of these items is a radio box: `radio_algo_a_star`.
- This is how it's set: `self.ui.radio_algo_a_star.setChecked(True)`.
- Currently, as the initial dialog opens up, the radio box is shown to be clicked as expected.
- A function `analyze_form` looks at the input from the widget.
- Part of this function is a snippet of code: `return  self.ui.radio_algo_a_star.isDown()`
- The above snippet returns `False` for some reason unless the radio button is pressed again when the form is running

*Question:**
How can I set a PyQT radio button to be clicked and have it return `True` using python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is [isChecked()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#checked-prop).

[isDown()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#down-prop) seems to be True only after the button has been pressed (as you describe).